# How to setup a minimap in multiplayer games?

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I wanted to setup a minimap for my multiplayer game. I am using photon for multiplayer.
Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: why are people downvoting this?? I can't find the information therefore i asked the question here

Comment: The question is too vague and you aren't displaying your scene and your game. I haven't downvoted you, but try to read carefully the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask document before writing another one.

Answer (score 1):

This question is probably too vague, but the rough strokes of how I would do it would be as follows

1. Render you scene (or only your environment) from a top down orthographic camera
2. Write a shader that transforms your player's positions to this camera's screenspace and draws a marker at their position (this can be quite difficult)
3. Render this out to a texture and display it on a mesh at the top of your screen / UI

This is not something that is super easy to do, you might be better just looking for one on the asset store.

If you have any difficulties then maybe ask another question specifically focusing on the area you're struggling with

best of luck